# ¿Cómo separar elementos y volverlos una lista única cada elemento para un string?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de la comunidad de Stack Over Flow,

Si tengo el siguiente string:

```
cadena = 23.253655
```

como haría para obtener este resultado:

```
['2'],['3'],['.'],['2'],['5'],['3'],['6'],['5'],['5']
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: `list(str(cadena))`

Answer (score 0):

No estoy metido mucho en python, pero estuve investigando y vi que puedes crear una lista de listas, bueno, puedes crear fragmentos de una lista:

primero tienes que desglosar la lista:

```
cadena= "25.362514"
    lista = list(cadena)
    print(lista)
    '''
    resultado: ['2', '5', '.', '3', '6', '2', '5', '1', '4']
    '''
```

Luego con la variable lista que hemos creado podemos sacar estos fragmentos de lista por medio de la compresión de listas:

```
'''
Declaramos una variable que nos servirá para poder separar la lista 
en la cantidad que deseemos
'''
n = 1

''' 
Luego hacemos el proceso para dividir la lista
'''
listaFinal = [lista[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lista), n)]

'''
resultado= [['2'], ['5'], ['.'], ['3'], ['6'], ['2'], ['5'], ['1'], ['4']]
'''
```

Con eso ya podrias accedar a la listaFinal y luego acceder al índice que quieras